# django - get 'REMOTE_USER' from middleware class

Tags: django, django-middleware

We use kerberos for our authentication. Using

```
request.META['REMOTE_USER']
```

I am able to get the authenticated user in my views.py however when I move this to a custom middleware class inside the

```
def process_request(self, request):
```

I keep getting the following error

```
user = request.META['REMOTE_USER']
KeyError: 'REMOTE_USER'
```

How do I read the authenticated user from my middleware?

Comment: You can get the authenticated user by using `request.user` - `request.user.is_authenticated()` assures you the authenticated user

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is your middleware is executing first than the middleware that fill out that info. Try to change the order of your middleware in the settings.py file.

Comment: my current custom middleware as at the bottom of the list. I'm assuming that it means it will be executed last. Is there a class I should have in there to expose it by anychance?

Comment: Is this request middleware or response middleware?  In the request cycle, it will be executed last.  In the response cycle it will be executed first.

Comment: Its not working by changing order. Any other solution?